# Flutter Community Charts - How to Show Times Chart point values

Tags: flutter, graph, charts, linechart

I'am using [Flutter Community Charts](https://pub.dev/packages/community_charts_flutter) and [Flutter Community Charts Common](https://pub.dev/packages/community_charts_common) packages in my project. I'm stuck in LineCharts on showing the line points values. Is there any possible way for it?

If there is, i am looking for it.

Thanks...

[image]

Comment: I never used these packages before, but I suggest you use syncfusion charts, it is more powerful and you can achieve what you want.